# Using Angular.js with ui-router and directive for unsaved changes, I lose field data on choosing to stay and save

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, angular-ui-router

I am calling my confirm-on-exit directive and checking for form is dirty. I am using a modal which gives the user the options to stay and save or leave the form. The problem is that when I choose to stay and save, the field data is lost. I am looking for another method of warning of unsaved changes without using event.preventDefault() and actually having the field data there to save.

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form" name="AddScacTask" novalidate confirm-on-exit>

app.directive('confirmOnExit', ['modalService', '$rootScope', '$stateParams', '$state', function (modalService, $rootScope, $stateParms, $state) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',       
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs, formCtrl) {

        onRouteChangeOff = $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', routeChange);

        function routeChange(event, newState, newParams, fromState, fromParams) {

            if (!scope.AddScacTask.$dirty) {
                return;
            }

            var modalOptions = {
                closeButtonText: 'No, I\'ll stay and save them.',
                actionButtonText: 'Yes, Leave and Ignore Changes',
                headerText: 'Unsaved Changes',
                bodyText: 'You have unsaved changes. Do you want to leave the page?'
            };

            modalService.showModal({}, modalOptions).then(function (result) {

                if (result) {
                    onRouteChangeOff(); //Stop listening for location changes
                    $state.transitionTo(newState); //Go to page they're interested in
                } else {
                    $state.transitionTo(fromState); //Stay on the page and have tab revert to fromState
                }
            });
            return;
        }
    }
};
```

}]);

Answer (score 0):

I had removed  event.preventDefault(); earlier for a different problem and it is absolutely needed.